# Query in codeigniter gives error

Tags: php, mysql, database, codeigniter

I wrote a small script which gives `internal server error 500` when it runs

```
for($d=0;$d<count($alltags);$d++)
    {
    $qu="insert into `elements`(`name`) values('".$alltags[$d]."')";
    $query=$this->db->query($qu);
        if($query==TRUE)
        {
            $add_count++;
        }
        else
        {
            $not_add_count++;
        }
    }
    return $add_count;
```

here:-  $addcount , $not_add_count are variables

and $alltags is an array

Comment: what is the error ?can u post it here?

Comment: internal server error 500

Comment: are u using htaccess??

Comment: You are running the insert queries in for loop. its bad practice. what will be the max value of the count($alltags)

Comment: .htaccess - for what? , i use it for removing 'index.php' , the max value of count is 100

Comment: Could you please provide more code? I am assuming you have debugging turned on, therefore if the problem was caused by the query you would have seen an error message by CI's database driver.

Comment: if u had use htaccess the remove it ..

Comment: there is no more code , it is just showing error on this , whta do i do?

Comment: see apache error log for additional information about 500 internal error.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to make life easier for yourself, read the documentation about

```
   $this->db->insert_batch();
```

you can pretty much do all of this with one line of code in codeigniter with an associative array or a simple class.  the way you are doing many small inserts is less efficient than doing one larger one.  additionally you are not using the codeigniter insert command, you you should probably worry about filtering your $alltags array for malicious code.  you don't want a [bobby drop tables problem](http://xkcd.com/327/)

then use the command

```
$this->db->affected_rows();
```

to return the number of rows affected by the last command.  you can count your array, so you don't need to bother with the $not_add_count because you can calculate if from the size of the array and the affected rows....
btw this would only be an issue if you have turned off all errors and you have something like a key violation. otherwise it should insert all rows.